# Concatenate one character from string 1 and second character from string 2

Tags: c++

I want to concatenate two strings but it like odd position characters from strin1 and even position characters from stri2.
This is what i have done:

```
string mainvalue(string og2,string eg2)
{
    string odd=og2;
    string even=eg2;
    string s3;
    reverse(odd.begin(),odd.end());
    cout<<"Main ordered text is :"<<odd<<endl;

    int length1=odd.length();
    int length2=even.length();

    for(int i=0;i<length1;i++)
    {
        for(int j=0;j<length2;j++)
        {
            s3 += odd[j]+even[j];
        }
    }

    cout<<"Complete text is :"<<s3<<endl;
    //return s3;
}
```

Output is look like : :▌π═▌π═▌π═

Comment: "This is what i have done is," OK, and? What happens when you compile/run it? Does it not work? How not? Is there a question here?

Comment: *Is it ok?* run it and see if you get the right output then yes, if it doesnt work ask a more specific question. if it does you can go to CodeReview.SE.

Comment: Do you really mean "interleave" rather than "concatenate"?

Comment: Output is something like : :▌π═▌π═▌π═

Comment: Even aside from `char + char` not doing what you think it does - pretending it did, this wouldn't work, given that you are looping for `len1 * len2`, which will be too long. You will then be indexing out-of-bounds, hence _undefined behaviour_, so anything can happen, including weird output like that. Shouldn't you loop for either `min(` or `max(len1, len1)`? You'll need to decide how to handle cases where the 2 lengths are different, if you allow that.

Comment: @krunal [Put those details in your question, not the comments (use the edit button or this link)](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/38225797/edit).

Comment: P.S: `s3 += odd[j]+even[j];` youre adding together the numberical values of two characters here. This is most likely not what you want.

Comment: @krunal  What do this identifiers og2 and  eg2 mean?

Comment: first of all i have partition my main string in two groups that is og2 and eg2. now i  want to merge them..

Comment: My main string's odd position characters are in og2 and even group characters are in eg2

Comment: Why are you doing `reverse`?  Maybe your function should be focused on doing just what you say you want to do, and not do all of these extraneous things like `reverse`.  Also, what if either string is longer than the other string?  What is done with the left-over characters from the longer string?

Comment: Now I get it: you want the odd positions *in the result* to come from `og2`, you don't want the characters from the odd positions in `og2`. Sorry for that. (Old comment removed.)

Answer (score 0):

The reason for your strange output is that you're adding two characters, and adding two alphabetical characters rarely gives a printable result.

But your code would be incorrect even if you could add characters to make strings, as your result would basically be `length1` copies of the desired result.

Assuming that the input strings are of equal length, one simple solution is to alternately take one character from each string.

This assumes that the first element is "odd" - if it's "even", just swap the two lines in the loop:

```
string mainvalue(string odds, string evens)
{
    string merged;
    for (string::size_type i = 0; i < odds.size(); ++i)
    {
        merged += odds[i];
        merged += evens[i];
    }
    return merged;
}
```

You could also do something like this:

```
string mainvalue(string odds, string evens)
{
    auto merged = string {odds.size() + evens.size(), ' '};
    auto odd = odds.begin();
    auto even = evens.begin();
    auto out = merged.begin();
    while (odd != odds.end())
    {
        *out++ = *odd++;
        *out++ = *even++;
    }
    return merged;
}
```